# How to slice optional arguments in RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

Actually i have the following RegExp expression:

`/^(?:(?:\,([A-Za-z]{5}))?)+$/g`

So the accepted input should be something like ,IGORA but even ,IGORA,GIANC,LOLLI is valid and i would be able to slice the string to 3 group  in this case, in other the group number should be equals to the user input that pass the RegExp test.

i was trying to do something like this in JavaScript but it return only the last value

```
 var str = ',GIANC,IGORA';
      var arr = str.match(/^(?:(?:\,([A-Za-z]{5}))?)+$/).slice(1);
      alert(arr);
```

So the output is 'IGORA' while i would it to be 'GIANC' 'IGORA'

Here is another example

```
/^([A-Z]{5})(?:(?:\,([A-Za-z]{2}))?)+$/g
```

test of regexp may have at least 5 chart string but it also can have other 5 chart string separated with a comma so from input

IGORA,CIAOA,POPOP

I would have an array of `["IGORA","CIAOA","POPOP"]`

Comment: You are repeating the group which will give you the value of the last repetition in group 1. Why not split on a comma?

Comment: @Thefourthbird i wouldn't use split as this is just one part of regex i'm going to use and the value that will be checked by the following expression is optional in the user input. Do you suggest anyway to use split in this case?

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the words in a capturing surrounded by an optional preceding comma or an optional trailing comma.

You can test the [regex here](https://regex101.com/r/5OHAIc/1): `,?([A-Za-z]+),?`

```js
const pattern = /,?([A-Za-z]+),?/gm;
const str = `,IGORA,GIANC,LOLLI`;
let matches = [];

let match;

// Iterate until no match found
while ((m = pattern.exec(str))) {

  // The first captured group is the match
  matches.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

Explanation:

> `\b` word boundary (starting or ending a word)
>
> `\w` a word ([A-z])
>
> `{5}` 5 characters of previous

So it matches all 5-character words but not NANANANA

```js
var str = 'IGORA,CIAOA,POPOP,NANANANA';
var arr = str.match(/\b\w{5}\b/g);
console.log(arr); //['IGORA', 'CIAOA', 'POPOP']
```

If you only wish to select words separated by commas and nothing else, you can test for them like so:

> `(?<=,\s*|^)` preceded by `,` with any number of trailing space, OR is the first word in list.
>
> `(?=,\s*|$)` followed by `,` and any number of trailing spaces OR is last word in list.

In the following code, POPOP and MOMMA are rejected because they are not separated by a comma, and NANANANA fails because it is not 5 character.

```js
var str = 'IGORA, CIAOA, POPOP MOMMA, NANANANA, MEOWI';
var arr = str.match(/(?<=,\s*|^)\b\w{5}\b(?=,\s*|$)/g);
console.log(arr); //['IGORA', 'CIAOA', 'MEOWI']
```

If you can't have any trailing spaces after the comma, just leave out the `\s*` from both `(?<=,\s*|^)` and `(?=,\s*|$)`.

Comment: The regexp have to check if there is comma separator and the input should be optional, as someone can write IGORACIAOA,POPOP with your solution i'm gonna accept anyway that input while i have to accept it only if there is comma separator between 5char

Comment: Updated to reject any words not separated by comma.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do this, but I found that one of the simple ways is by using the `replace` method, as it can replace all instances that match that regex.

For example:

```js
var regex = /^(?:(?:\,([A-Za-z]{5}))?)+$/g;
var str = ',GIANC,IGORA';
var arr = [];
str.replace(regex, function(match) {
    arr[arr.length] = match;
    return match;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Also, in my code snippet you can see that there is an extra coma in each string, you can solve that by changing line 5 to `arr[arr.length] = match.replace(/^,/, '')`.